# How To Retain or keep hidden div element after page reloaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a **hidden div** on my page, I want to know what kind of way I can do to keep showing the **div** when the page is reloaded, with the following example:

This my html :

```
  <div class="card-body">
      <div class="overlay" id="kt_datatable_nodata">
        <div class="overlay-wrapper rounded bg-light text-center">
          <p class="font-weight-bold text-center">Pilih data untuk dibandingkan</p>
          <a href='#right-modal' class='btn' data-toggle='modal'>Change Data</a>
        </div>
       </div>
       <!--begin::Table-->
       <div id="kt_datatable_fetch_display"></div>
      <!--End::Table-->
 </div>
```

This My javascript :

```
$('#kt_datatable').on('click','tr button', function() {
           var id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'src/khu-pusat/compare/right-side/right-value.php',
            data: {
                'rowid': id
            },
            success: function(data) {
             $('#kt_datatable_nodata').addClass('hidden');
              $('#kt_datatable_fetch_display').html(data);
              
            }
        });
    })
```

this **right-value.php** :

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db_connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['rowid'])) {
    $id = $_POST['rowid'];
    $query = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT* FROM data_penilaian where id = '$id'");
    $no = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
?>

<form class="leftForms" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="position" value="<?= $row['position']; ?>">
</form>
<?php
    }
} ?>
```

here what I want to do is what kind of way I can do to keep the ***kt_datatable_fetch_display*** on or after the page is reloaded. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use `localStorage` to keep track of the hidden `<div>`. When the page is reloaded, load the info from `localStorage` and if it exists, hide the `<div>` again.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand quite what you want to do, but the only way I'm thinking you could achieve this it's to make your button to add a query param that must be your id.

Exaple:

```
// This goint to redirect to the new URL
$('#kt_datatable').on('click','tr button', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var yourSiteURL = "http://localhost";

    window.location.href = `yourSiteURL/${id}`;
});

/*
    When DOM loads read query params and make your ajax req
    So, no matter page reloads, always goint to make the ajax req and fill your div
*/ 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href);
    var id = searchParams.get("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'src/khu-pusat/compare/right-side/right-value.php',
        data: {
            'rowid': id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#kt_datatable_nodata').addClass('hidden');
            $('#kt_datatable_fetch_display').html(data);            
        }
    });
})
```